# Set Button to Unlocked

Tags: excel, vba, button, password-protection

SO I have a sheet that protect and unprotects in VBA. This works fine for the most part EXCEPT for my form reset button, which does not allow anyone to click the button (coded below).

Is there a way to set a property in the button to unlocked? So that when the macro prior to it creates it and then locks the sheet, you will still be able to click it?

```
With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(545, 42, 72, 18)
        .Name = "NEWNCR"
        .Caption = "New NCR #"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("NEWNCR")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "populatencrnumber"
```

Maybe something like

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("NEWNCR")).Locked = False
```

This exact example doesn't work of course. But something like that exists, right?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `.Enabled = True`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("NEWNCR").Locked = True/False` or enabled the same approach

Comment: Nathan yours worked. Another issue I had that I didn't think of was that every time I clicked that formreset button, it was stacking the buttons on top of each other. Which makes them not work. So now the button deletes the old button (if it's there) before putting in a new, unlocked one. Thanks again!